# C#/.NET: how do I close the application from a parent window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows application that has 2 **Forms**. From one form I am opening a 2nd form.
When opening the 2nd form I am hiding 1 form and in the second foem I am starting a thread.
Now I want to close the application.
But I was not able to do that.

On my 1st form I have tried:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1(this, tcpClient);
frm.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
Application.Exit();
```

But the application is not ending. It still running.

Any idea how to stop that?

EDIT (CODE Included):

On 1st form's button click event:

```
this.Hide();
Form1 frm = new Form1(this, tcpClient, serverMsg);
frm.Show();
```

On 1st form's button FormClosed event:

```
MessageBox.Show("Before");
Application.Exit();
```

On 2nd form's load event I am calling a method startThread(); on this method

```
ilThread = new Thread(incomingListener);
ilThread.IsBackground = true;
ilThread.Start();
```

Comment: Might be worth posting the code up that you use for starting your thread.

Comment: How are you closing the 2nd form?

Comment: And what errors are you getting when calling Application.Exit()? Is that line of code even being called?

Comment: Thank you all for all efforts, actually I have opened socket,and that was not closed, so after I close that socket Application.Exit(); start working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `frm.ShowDialog()` you're opening a modal window. The code will stop at that point until you specify a `DialogResult` on frm. I.e. `frm.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;`.

If you use `frm.Show()` that might work for you.

Comment: +1. Well spotted. If @openidsujoy fixes this issue, then the next one will may be the threading (as per my answer)!

Comment: Cheers. I'll be sure to return the +1 should he post anything further.

Comment: if I used "frm.Show()" then it immediately close the entire application.

Comment: I want to close the Application on second Form's closing event.

Comment: You need to show us some more code, i.e. what happens on your closing event, what happens when you set your thread up. Help us help  you!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**- See @GenericTypeTea's answer first. If after doing that you are still having issues see mine:

From what you describe it sounds like you have left the thread running. Have you tried creating the thread as a [background thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) or making sure you end that thread in a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't set the Thread you started as a background thread. Background threads are stopped automatically when application closes. Foreground threads will keep it alive.

To set thread as background thread use `IsBackground` property.

See [Thread.IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx).

Otherwise you should take care yourself of stopping the started thread before exiting the application.